# Change the default domain of Client() in unittest of Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-unittest

I am writing a unit test for Django views.

```
class TestLog(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test for Contact"""
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()
        try:
            self.bob = User.objects.create_user("mojo","b@example.com", "bmojo")
        except :
            print ''

    def test_get_emails(self):
        response = self.c.get('/text/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


    def test_htmlemils(self):
        response = self.c.get('/emails/html/upload')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The c = Client() takes the 'http://testserver' as domain which i want to overwrite ,i want to add my real domain in that test client ,is their way to customize the test Client ?

Comment: FYI: TestCase automatically adds `self.client` as an instance of Client, so you don't need to do `self.c = Client()` in `setUp`. Just change `self.c.get` in your test methods to `test.client.get` :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Django's `Client` [extends `RequestFactory`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/client.py#L326) so you should be able to pass in extra params as keyword arguments.

Try:

```
response = self.c.get('/emails/html/upload', SERVER_NAME="mydomain.com")
```

Comment: yes working i directly add SERVER_NAME in client like

C = Client(SERVER_NAME="mydomain.com")

Answer (score 1):

The code can help not only in unit test, but it can also help for DRF to use context in a serializer
`ResponseSerializer(instance=obj, context={'request': get_request}).data`

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
rf = RequestFactory()
rf.defaults['SERVER_NAME'] = 'my-site.com'
get_request = rf.get('/hello/')
```

Comment: Giving some words explaining your answer goes a long way beyond a "just code" answer.